# Remove column border

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the border that is wrapped around my image, thumbnail label. I tried adding another class "noborder" and give it under my .col-md-4.noborder css rule, I give border 0 none and box-shadow 0 none but it doesn't work. Please help.

```css
.col-md-4.noborder {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>J2EE</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script
         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script
         src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navbarscroll.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body> 
          <div class="container">
         <div classs="row">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4 noborder">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                     <img src="..." alt="...">
                     <div class="caption">
                        <h3 align="center">Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p align="center">...</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 noborder">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                     <img src="..." alt="...">
                     <div class="caption">
                        <h3 align="center">Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p align="center">...</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 noborder">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                     <img src="..." alt="...">
                     <div class="caption">
                        <h3 align="center">Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p align="center">...</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border is on the thumbnail class. This should remove it.

```
.thumbnail {
  border: 0 !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the border is declared to `.thumbnail`

```
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

override it with your custom css.

```
.thumbnail{
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you add noborder class to thumbnail div

```
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail noborder">
             <img src="..." alt="...">
             <div class="caption">
                <h3 align="center">Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p align="center">...</p>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <Style>
         .noborder {
         border: 0 !important; 
         }
       </style>
```

OR

```
.thumbnail {
 border: 0 !important;  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.col-md-4` has no border property set. Setting it to no border will not do anything since it didn't have border to begin with.

To specifically set `.thumbnail` in `.col-md-4.noborder` to have no border, you can refer to the snippet below.

```css
.col-md-4.noborder .thumbnail, .col-md-4.noborder .thumbnail img {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>J2EE</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script
         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script
         src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navbarscroll.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body> 
          <div class="container">
         <div classs="row">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4 noborder">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                     <img src="..." alt="...">
                     <div class="caption">
                        <h3 align="center">Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p align="center">...</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 noborder">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                     <img src="..." alt="...">
                     <div class="caption">
                        <h3 align="center">Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p align="center">...</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 noborder">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                     <img src="..." alt="...">
                     <div class="caption">
                        <h3 align="center">Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p align="center">...</p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```